# When should HTTP Form POST be preferred over Ajax?

Tags: ajax, web-applications, http-post, form-submit

I have recently started using ajax. Before that i have primarily used form submission to send the data to server. But with using ajax, i feel like i we can avoid form submission in most of the cases. Even in those case where we need to go from one page to another page(for example if i want to see the detail of particular customer on click of customer link in table, i can make ajax call to server and get the html response and append it on current page which earlier was handled thru form submission which was bit slow also).

So i would like to know the stuff where form submission should be preferred over ajax?

Comment: Ajax is only available when Javascript is enabled. Forms are pure HTML.

Comment: You could use Ajax and then provide form submission as a fallback if a user (for some reason) doesn't have JS enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly, Ajax can be used. But keep in mind that it requires additional effort in implementation.

Also, There are a couple of cases where forms are still needed:

- File upload
- Sending data to some other server
- A form that triggers a download

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a very wide question, and i'll try to answer it a bit deeper.

**There are some reasons to use a regular HTTP POST instead of Ajax if needed:**

1. HTTP POST is a part of the HTTP 1.1 standard as specified by World
   [Wide Web Consortium (W3C)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)
   and therefore works
   in *any* HTTP 1.1 compliant browser.
2. Ajax requires JavaScript support. Even *if* your user's browser supports JavaScript, different browsers run JavaScript using
   different engines and you might experience browser specific errors.
3. Ajax requires a whole different level of error handling.

   **Let me explain:** When a user sends a POST request to your server and some error occurs (e.g. the connection is lost) the user will receive a fully visible error in the browser because the browser itself will notify the user something went wrong. When you use Ajax you have to write / implement all of this error handling yourself.

   *Example:* User A is visiting your blog and wants to post a comment using Facebook OAUTH which you implemented on your blog. User enters a comment text in the comment field and presses the comment button and the result? *Nothing happens*. 
   **Why?** There could be a multitude of reasons e.g. lost connection, unhandled content errors, server errors, compability errors, security errors like a missing/invalid server certificate, Facebook OAUTH communication error etc.

   Doing the same thing with a HTTP POST *will* result in an error that is visible to the user.

**More generic Ajax / JavaScript issues**

1. When loading a page using an HTTP request, it's visible in the browser when the page is loaded. Ajax is often loaded *after* the page loads and therefore, the browser does not notify the user that a resource is loading.
2. If you load resources (e.g. blog posts) using Ajax, they will not be indexed by Google, because Google does not run JavaScript. Therefore, less people will find your site/content.
3. Unresponsive Responsive design; Ajax heavy sites can be so CPU- and network traffic intensive that a page actually takes *a lot* longer to load than it would have taken using plain old HTML.

**Unfortunately, a modern web site often really needs JavaScript. So, how to handle the above?**

1. Use the right technique where applicable (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)
2. Handle errors.
3. When POSTing using Ajax, give the user "tactile feedback" by showing loading animations if you expect the response from the server to take more than one second.
4. **Unobtrusive JavaScript**.

   Unobtrusive JavaScript allows users that do not have JavaScript enabled to use at least the basic functionality on your site.

   **Example:** User A enters your blog with a Non-JavaScript Browser and clicks the comment button. A popup window appears where User A enters her comment and makes a regular post to the server and is redirected back to your blog post. 
   User B enters your blog with a JavaScript enabled browser. Right under your blog post, there is a comment field and a submit button. User B enters her comment and clicks the submit button and an Ajax request is sent to the server. The page is updated with the posted comment and the user never have to be redirected.

   Basically, unobtrusive JavaScript is possible by always loading your regular plain old HTML page. After loading the page, you run a JavaScript replacing your html elements and links with JavaScript anchors and elements. This way, a browser that does not allow JavaScript execution can use your site.

**Resources:**

Unobtrusive JavaScript

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-unobtrusive/%2F&ei=deUzUfekB6OH4AS09IFo&usg=AFQjCNGZwD9bsz52xK3zGpDQTjyGzO4EHQ
- http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-technique/
- http://www.searchenginepeople.com/blog/unobtrusive-javascript.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Ajax error handling

- http://www.unseenrevolution.com/jquery-ajax-error-handling-function/
- http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/09/creating-an-ajax-component-handling-errors-and-loading-notifications-with-publish-and-subscribe/
- http://aaronsaray.com/blog/2010/08/24/how-to-handle-ajax-errors-with-jquery/

I hope this answers your question!

Answer (score -1):

There isn't much difference between the two.
I generally prefer ajax over regular forms.

Whatever method you choose the important thing is how to make it secure.

For example if you have a website where you accept data in post form. I can make a form and post thousands of lines of code to your website and your website will accept that because you dont know where the data is comming from. and example would be the registration page in your site.

It would be better if you send an md5 hash with your form to the users browser and save it in the session. So when the user submit the form you he/she will send back the hash to your server and there you can check it against the saved session value. Then you will know that its your site and not from some third person.