# submit form details using Ajax tp aspx page

Tags: asp.net, ajax, post, webforms

i want to send form details by mail,
i tried to do it with Json and it worked just fine
im trying to it with POST, by sending form details like in GET
i wrote this code in the HTML file

```
     function ContactPageAjax() {

     $.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: "Process.aspx/SendMailPost",
    data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
    dataType: "POST",

    error: function () {
        alert('Error');
    },
    success: function (res) {
        document.getElementById("thanks").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("contactForm").style.visibility = "hidden";
        alert("ok");
    } 
});
 }
```

and this code in the aspx file:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = false)]
public static void SendMailPost(String formVars)

{//email send code}
```

i tried to change String to Object and also some other types, it seems the problem is there but im not sure, when i run it the ajax call returns success.
but the code of the mail is not running, if i use Json type it works good

what do you think my problem is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post the form data to web method in aspx, **by serializing the form data into an array, Stringify it into a json**.

In the server side, **you will have to create a custom type containing a name value pair and the parameter of the page method will be an array of that custom type**. The reason being, the json serialized array should be able to be deserialized into the parameter of the web method for the ajax call to happen.

```
  function btnclick() {
        var array = $("#form1").serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "PageMethodTest.aspx/TestFormPost",
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'namevaluepair': $("#form1").serializeArray() }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: fnsuccesscallback,
            error: fnerrorcallback
        });
    }

    function fnsuccesscallback(data) {
        alert(data.d);

    }
    function fnerrorcallback(result) {
        alert(result.statusText);
    }



    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <table runat="server">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label id="lblName" runat="server" title="Name">
                        Name</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtName" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label id="lblCompany" runat="server" title="Company">
                        Company</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtCompany" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="button" style="width: 104px" value="Submit" onclick="btnclick();" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

Server code:

```
 [WebMethod, ScriptMethod]
    public static String TestFormPost(NameValue[] namevaluepair)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(NameValue nvp in namevaluepair)
        {
            builder.Append(nvp.Name + ": " + nvp.Value + ";"); 
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
}

 public class NameValue
{
    public String Name;
    public String Value;
}
```

Comment: what will be quicker? this or JSON?

Comment: above method also uses json only.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173877/when-should-http-form-post-be-preferred-over-ajax refer this post if ur query is which is better - form submission or AJAX..